# Calculate $\eta^2$ for repeated measures anova with lme4 in R

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I know this is a subject of controversy, but I'm not interested in why p-values and effect sizes are bad but how I can calculate the latter based on the `lmer()` function. In psychology literally every supervisor wants to have $\eta^2$ or $\eta^2_{partial}$ reported in ANOVA results. So no room for idealism here.

I'm aware of calculating the effect size with the help of the `car` and `heplots` package, but calling this way beginner-unfriendly would be the understatement of the year.

Is there any way to calculate $\eta^2$ or $\eta^2_{partial}$ for a `lmer()` anova (not the overall $R^2$ like one could get with `sjstats::r2()`) or the residuals sum of squares to write a short function to calculate it myself?

For example, if `anova(lmer(...))` returns an ANOVA output like this

```
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
A       1090549  1090549   1   175    25.7756   9.747e-07 ***
B       36119    36119     1   175    0.8537    0.3568
```

I'd like to get something like this

```
                 eta^2
(Intercept) 0.95813226
A           0.16879768
B           0.03596987
```

Comment: There are functions in sjstats that also calculate omega or eta squared, but these require an object of class `aov` or similar, but if I recall right, `anova()` returns a data frame, which is not consistent across different models. I think here is the problem why it's rather difficult to calculate eta squared from these objects.

Comment: I know, one can calculate eta squared for `aov` objects, but I also need it for repeated measure ANOVAs. I really like the syntax of `lme4` but if theres no way to calculate eta squared I'll have to switch to `ez::ezANOVA()`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the _afex_ package may help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel gave me the right hint with the `afex` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/afex.pdf). The syntax is quiet similar to the one in `lme4`. Assuming you have `IQ` as the dependend variable, `A` as a between subject factor and `B` and `C` as within subject factors, one could write

```
afex::aov_4(IQ ~ A + (B * C|id), data = df, anova_table = "pes")
```

with `id` as the persons identification and `pes` to calculate $\eta^2_{partial}$ instead of the generalized $\eta^2$. One would obtain a table like this

```
Effect    df      MSE         F    pes p.value
 A       1, 28 32954.92   9.91 **  .26    .004
 B       1, 28  3002.32 15.25 ***  .35   .0005
 A:B     1, 28  3002.32      1.49  .05     .23
 C       1, 28  8583.84      1.21  .04     .28
 A:C     1, 28  8583.84      0.18 .006     .68
 B:C     1, 28   821.29      0.63  .02     .43
 A:B:C   1, 28   821.29      0.47  .02     .50
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't indicate how it would be calculated for a mixed model.  I wonder .

Comment: @SalMangiafico Take a look at `afex::mixed()`. But since the package developers make use of `lme4::lmer()`, I doubt that effect sizes are calculated.